# How do I check if the value of an input is a number using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I need to check if the value of the input consists of numbers(0-9). Thanks for helping.

Comment: [Try this](https://www.google.com/search?q=jQuery+check+if+value+is+a+number)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to use `isNumeric` like this:

```
if($.isNumeric( input ) && parseInt(input)<10 && parseInt(input)>=0){
```

...
}

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regular Expressions:

var result = /^[\d]+$/.test(yourInput);

Comment: Maybe a little more explanation would be helpful? I don't think this is going to be fully obvious to someone new to regex.